# Installation sonata-project/user-bundle symfony 3.3 lts

Tags: symfony, sonata-user-bundle

I create symfony app by 'symfony new' and get symfony 3.3
After that installed "sonata admin" and "Sonata doctrine orm admin" via composer
All ok. Admin skeleton is working.
But when i run "composer require sonata-project/user-bundle" i have version conflict for symfony/form

`Problem 1
    - Installation request for sonata-project/user-bundle ^3.5 -> satisfiable by sonata-project/user-bundle[3.5.0].
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - sonata-project/user-bundle 3.5.0 requires symfony/form ^2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/form[v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.21, v2.8.22, v2.8.23, v2.8.24, v2.8.25, v2.8.26, v2.8.27, v2.8.28, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/form v2.8.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    ...
    - don't install symfony/form v2.8.9|don't install symfony/symfony v3.3.10
    - Installation request for symfony/symfony (locked at v3.3.10, required as 3.3.*) -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[v3.3.10].`

User bundle not supported by symfony lts? What is the best solution for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the 4.x branch of SonataUserBundle which is still in developpement (already pretty stable however). A realease might be [available late 2017](https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataUserBundle/issues/879#issuecomment-340750971)  :

> "sonata-project/user-bundle": "dev-master",

More information on dependencies on packagist : https://packagist.org/packages/sonata-project/user-bundle

Comment: Thx a lot for help